# Spring data ldap configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ldap

I'm having trouble configuring spring-data-ldap in a web app.
I summarize what I have done:
I created a maven (called ldap-model) project, with the spring-data-ldap dependency, I created the User.java (Entry) class and the corresponding Repository: UserRepository.
Then I created a new spring mvc web project, with the liberation dependency created before (ldap-model).
I wanted to use the xml configuration, so:

root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->


<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:ldap.properties" />
<context:annotation-config />

<ldap:context-source id="contextSource"
    password="${ldap.contextSource.password}" url="${ldap.contextSource.url}"
    username="${ldap.contextSource.userDn}" base="${ldap.contextSource.base}"></ldap:context-source>

<ldap:repositories base-package="eu.test.ldap.repository">
</ldap:repositories>

<ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate"
    context-source-ref="contextSource"></ldap:ldap-template>

<bean class="eu.test.webapp.UserService">
</bean>
```

Here I have the first problem with tag ldap:repositories , with Ctrl + Space it's suggested to me, but it does not compile giving this error :

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [repositories] Offending resource: file [C:/Progetti/
 Workspace di test/ldap-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
- Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [repositories]
```

Following the rest of the code :

UserService.java

```
public class UserService implements BaseLdapNameAware {
private final UserRepository userRepo;
private LdapName baseLdapPath;

@Autowired
public UserService(UserRepository userRepo) {
    this.userRepo = userRepo;
}

public void find()
{
    User u = userRepo.findByUid("test.test");
    System.out.println(u.getUid());
}

@Override
public void setBaseLdapPath(LdapName baseLdapPath) {
    this.baseLdapPath = baseLdapPath;

}}
```

ldap.properties

```
ldap.contextSource.url=*********
ldap.contextSource.userDn=cn=*********
ldap.contextSource.password=*********
ldap.contextSource.base=*********
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="eu.test.webapp" />
```

HomeController.java

```
@Controller
 public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

@Autowired
private UserService userService;


@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

     userService.find();


    return "home";
}
```

}

Is there something wrong besides the error given?

I also tried to create a java configuration, not xml
I created a new spring mvc web project, with the liberation dependency created before (ldap-model).

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:ldap.properties")
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"eu.test.*"})
 @Profile("default")
 @EnableLdapRepositories(basePackages = "eu.test.ldap.repository.**")
  public class AppConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.contextSource.url"));
    contextSource.setBase(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.contextSource.base"));
    contextSource.setUserDn(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.contextSource.userDn"));
    contextSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.contextSource.password"));
    return contextSource;
}

@Bean
public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
    return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
}
```

}

ldap.properties like above

UserService.java

```
@Service
```

public class UserService {

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public String getUsernameByUid(String uid)
{
    return userRepository.findByUid(uid).getUsername();
}
```

}

HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {

    String username = userService.getUsernameByUid("nome.cognome");

    return "home";
}
```

}

I'm sure something is missing, userService is null

Does anyone have an example web project with these features?

Sorry for the english, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be a difference in parsing xml configuration since spring-ldap-core 2.3.
If you take a look at LdapNamespaceHandler class, you can see that no handler is defined for tag "repositories".
It sounds strange because there is no equivalent change in spring-ldap.xsd.
Anyway, if you want to use xml configuration approach, you can solve using spring-ldap-core 2.2 instead of spring-ldap-core 2.3, simply modifying your pom.xml.

Ciao.